# C# WPF - Pass value from click event to other class file

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, radgridview

I'm using `RadGridView` that has 11 rows and many columns, i only shows 2 columns which is Name and Type. I create a `ContextMenu`  for the rows, and will open to **new window** if i click it. Let's say i have 3 different values in `columnType` which is A, B, C. and i have click event for the `ContextMenu` like this :

```
public void GridContextMenu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = (e.OriginalSource as RadMenuItem).DataContext as MenuItem;
    typeValue = (GridView.SelectedItem).columnType;
    switch (item.Text)
    {
        case "Edit]":
            if (typeValue == "A")
            {
                selectedItem = GridView.SelectedItem;
                editA.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            else if (typeValue == "B")
            {
                selectedItem = GridView.SelectedItem;
                editB.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            else if (typeValue == "C")
            {
                selectedItem = GridView.SelectedItem;
                editC.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Delete":
            this.GridView.Items.Remove(this.GridView.SelectedItem);
            break;
    }
}
```

So i can get like `selectedItem.columnType` or `selectedItem.column3`. But the problem is, i don't know how to pass the `selectedItem` values to the window that's just opened? I tried the `{ get;set; }` static class for the `selectedItem` but when i tried to call it from the new window, the values still null.

Comment: Pass the selecteditem value in constructor of that window. You must be instantiating it using new Window2().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a parameterized constructor for your `Window`, and pass your `SelectedItem` value on your `Window` instantiation. Something like this:

```
public partial class EditWindow : Window
{    
    public EditWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public EditWindow(YourObjectType selectedItem) : this()
    {
      var yourSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
EditWindow editWindow = new EditWindow(selectedItem);
editWindow.Show();
```

Comment: so in my `GridContextMenu_ItemClick` i uses `EditA editA = new EditA(selectedItem);` and i call it in my new window (EditA) with the code you gave me, but when i tried to call `yourSelectedItem.column3` or something else, it got me an error `object does not contain....` whats wrong?

Comment: Nvm i change the type object to my class. Now it works, but the value in yourSelectedItem.column still null?

Comment: Make sure that you set the `SelectionMode` property of your `GridView` to `Single`, assuming that user can only select one item in the list.

Comment: ah i figure it out. Thanks for the answer. but i have another question that maybe you can help me. i have 3 ComboBox in my newwindow and i want my `combobox1.selectedvalue` to be the value of the `selectedItem.column3`. It works but only works in combobox1, when i set the combobox2, the value become null. Any clue about that?

Comment: You can post a new question for it and don't forget to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).